# Set Country Region to enable Wi-Fi channels 12 and 13

Tags: linux, wifi

First of, we are not using a standard linux, we are using an embedded linux from NXP.

The problem that we have is that we are not able to set the country region to enable channels 12 and 13.

We have installed CRDA and we are using a Wi-Fi chipset from Cypress (broadcom)

The problem:

When the Linux boots, we don't have the wlan0 up, so ifconfig shows this:

```
13:52:15 root@i:~> ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1%1995577040/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:18944 (18.5 KiB)  TX bytes:18944 (18.5 KiB)

13:58:41 root@i:~> iw dev
phy#0
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 4
                wdev 0x1
                addr 00:90:4c:11:22:33
                type managed
```

If the wlan0 is not enabled, we can change the region country:

```
iw reg set JP
13:54:15 root@i:~> cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: JP
cfg80211:  DFS Master region: JP
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (                         dfs_cac_time)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (4910000 KHz - 4990000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5030000 KHz - 5090000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000                          mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000                          mBm), (0 s)
cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
```

So, if we check the iw list, we can see that channels 12 and 13 are enabled:

```
13:58:27 root@i:~> iw list |grep MHz
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm)
```

The problem is: When we bring up the wlan0, using ifup wlan0 or ip lik set wlan0 up, the iw reset the channels 11 and 12:

```
14:01:53 root@i:~> iw list |grep MHz
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
```

Broadcom uses the command tool "wl". We only can use this tool, once wlan0 is up.
If we check the channels available, we can see that channels 11 and 12 are not available:

```
14:02:03 root@i:~> wl chan_info
Channel 1       B Band
Channel 2       B Band
Channel 3       B Band
Channel 4       B Band
Channel 5       B Band
Channel 6       B Band
Channel 7       B Band
Channel 8       B Band
Channel 9       B Band
Channel 10      B Band
Channel 11      B Band
```

If we set the country region, using wl:

```
14:03:32 root@i:~> wl country GB

14:04:25 root@i:~> wl chan_info
Channel 1       B Band
Channel 2       B Band
Channel 3       B Band
Channel 4       B Band
Channel 5       B Band
Channel 6       B Band
Channel 7       B Band
Channel 8       B Band
Channel 9       B Band
Channel 10      B Band
Channel 11      B Band
Channel 12      B Band
Channel 13      B Band
```

We can see that channels 12 and 13 are available, but iw is not showing these channels:

```
14:01:53 root@i:~> iw list |grep MHz
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
```

If we try to set again the country region, it doesn't work.

```
14:07:55 root@i:~> iw reg set GB
14:08:01 root@i:~> cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)

14:01:53 root@i:~> iw list |grep MHz
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
```

**Questions:**

1-Why ifup changes/reset the "channels"?
During ifup the 'driver' is loaded:

```
13:59:45 root@i:~> ifup wlan0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device

Dongle Host Driver, version 1.141.92 (r)
Compiled in drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd
wl_android_wifi_on in
mmc0: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
mmc0: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
mmc0: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
mmc0: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
mmc0: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
mmc0: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (6 bytes)
F1 signature OK, socitype:0x1 chip:0xa9a6 rev:0x1 pkg:0x3
DHD: dongle ram size is set to 524288(orig 524288) at 0x0
dhdsdio_write_vars: Download, Upload and compare of NVRAM succeeded.
dhd_bus_init: enable 0x06, ready 0x06 (waited 0us)
wifi_platform_get_mac_addr
Firmware up: op_mode=0x0005, MAC=60:f1:89:cb:cb:17
Firmware version = wl0: Dec 11 2014 04:20:45 version 7.10.323.34 (r520360) FWID 01-ea2beeba
dhd_wlfc_init(): successfully enabled bdcv2 tlv signaling, 79
dhd_wlfc_init: query wlfc_mode succeed, fw_caps=0x1c
dhd_wlfc_init(): wlfc_mode=0x1c, ret=0
CFG80211-ERROR) wl_update_wiphybands : error reading vhtmode (-23)
wl_create_event_handler(): thread:wl_event_handler:246 started
CFG80211-ERROR) wl_event_handler : tsk Enter, tsk = 0x8a46143c
```

2-Maybe the problem is that I have to execute the wl tool before bring up the wlan0 interface, but wl command cannot find the interface if it is not up.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the driver. Manufacturer confirmed the bug.

Comment: Could you show please some reference?